# How do I get the Count from a query expression in linq?

Tags: vb.net, linq, asp.net-3.5

What I have right now is this:

```
Dim users = From users In tempTable _
            Distinct Select users.Item("s_userid")
Dim usersCount As Integer = users.Count
```

But I pretty sure I shouldn't have to do that. I should be able to get the count in/from that first linq query. What am I missing?

Comment: tempTable.Rows.Count ? 
What type is tempTable? Is this a entity framework/linq2sql call?

You have given us very little information to work with. (@ Keith Nicholas - I agree )

Comment: Is this LINQ-To-Objects or LINQ-To-SQL?

Comment: The table is a DataTable. I'm not using Entity Framework. I believe this would be considered Linq-To-Objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim distinctUserCount = (From users In tempTable
                    Let UserID = CInt(users.Item("s_userid"))
                    Select UserID).Distinct.Count
```

Another method would be to group the DataRows by your UserID-Column:

```
distinctUserCount  = (From users In tempTable
                    Let UserID = CInt(users("s_userid"))
                    Group users By UserID Into Group).Count
```

The "native" ADO.NET approach:

```
Dim view = new DataView(tempTable)
Dim TblDistinctUsers = view.ToTable(true, "s_userid")
distinctUserCount = TblDistinctUsers.Rows.Count
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wec2b2e6%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim userCount = (From users In tempTable _
            Distinct Select users.Item("s_userid")).Count
```

Comment: Isn't it better to `Distinct` behind the `Select`? `(From users In tempTable Select users.Item("s_userid")).Distinct.Count`